# my IDE throws an error in ''every' method (dart)

Tags: dart

is evey() method in dart still exist in SDK 3.2.2 version? because it throws an error in my IDE

I read the documentation but I can't find the exact answer on my question. I hope someone could help me!. Anyway, I am a beginner in dart

Comment: There are 6 different `every` methods from different classes, go to [Dart API docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.5/index.html) and search "every"

Comment: There's a link for that: https://api.flutter.dev?search=every :)
EDIT: that'll show only the most common one.  Typing "every" into the search box once you're there, I see 13, not 6 in the current API.

Comment: No, that 13 includes `everything` and `everyElement`.  The other 5 are from `package:collection`, so not in the Dart API. I was right :D @RandalSchwartz

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, but I managed to find the answer, I got confused first but I later understand that 'evey()"  method is throwing error in 'String' data type.

Comment: Of course, if you want you can do `aString.characters.every()`

Answer (score 2):

It is.
The Dart 3.2.5 documentation includes: [Iterable.every](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.5/dart-core/Iterable/every.html) and [Stream.every](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.5/dart-async/Stream/every.html).

It would probably be easier to help you with the actual problem if you showed the code causing the error, the text of the error, and said what you expected to happen instead.
Without that, all we can safely say is that your code likely has a problem.